# How can I launch fragment in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

How can I use broadcast receiver to start/lunch fragment
for example :
if I need to **start/luanch** activity , I can use **intent** :

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    this.context = context;
    this.intent = intent;

    try {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        int messageID = bundle.getInt("id");

        intent = new Intent(context, GetAlarm.class);

        intent.putExtra("id",messageID);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I don't know how about fragment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must **luanch** intent and **putextera** and **sendactivity**.
Then you can launch fragment from activity.

Answer (score 3):

**Fragment** is a part of **Activity**. Without **Activity** you cannot launch a separate **Fragment**. You can launch an **Activity** with **Fragment**.

One way is to create **BroadcastReceiver** inner class in **Activity** to launch **Fragment**.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Put this in your Broadcast Receiver:

```
activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
activityIntent.putExtra("fragment", "fragment2");
activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(activityIntent);
```

and beneath the code you use to set your **fragment pager adapter**:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    if (bundle.getString("fragment") != null) {
        /*Log.w(getClass().toString(), bundle.getString("fragment"));*/
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
}
```

This code is usually below something like this:

```
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

        });
```

Just make sure it's beneath where you set your adapter, and not just your viewpager, or else you won't be able to navigate to any fragments via the viewpager.