# How to open a fragment from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I want to open a fragment through a sms-receiver, how should I implement that? Any help is appreciated.

Receiver source code:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String body, vsn;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle == null)
        return;

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
        PaymentTransaksi.setSmsDetail(body);

        Intent showPaymentForm = new Intent();
        showPaymentForm.setClassName("showPaymentForm",
                "id.dutapulsa.bayartagihan.PaymentTransaksi");
        showPaymentForm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment source code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    paymentRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_main, container,
                false);

    return paymentRootView;
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223298/how-can-i-launch-fragment-in-broadcast-receiver

Comment: What he said :-) if it is because you want a dialog, you can create an empty and transparent activity that adds the fragment. Then simply start that activity when receiving the broadcast

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I want to share my solution with the community because it is a common task.

1.) In your layout file (e.g. of your MainActivity) create a container, which will be replaced by the current fragment.

2.) Add the following code snippet to your Activity (don't forget to change it a bit, if neccessary)

```
  public void updateFragment(Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
    String tag = clazz.getName();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, tag, args);
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

3.) Now you can simply call this method from your BroadcastReceiver, like this one:

```
updateFragment(ContentFragment.class, null);
```

4.) For dialogs I extend from DialogFragment and have the following method in my Activity:

```
    public static void showProgressDialog(Activity activity, String title, String message) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(ProgressDialogFragment.ARG_TITLE, title);
    bundle.putString(ProgressDialogFragment.ARG_MESSAGE, message);

    ProgressDialogFragment mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialogFragment();
    mProgressDialog.setArguments(bundle);
    mProgressDialog.setRetainInstance(true);
    mProgressDialog.show(fragmentManager, "Dialog");
}
```

Hope I can help! ;-)