# How can I launch a fragment from a Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

How can I launch my a particular fragment within an activity from my Parse Broadcast Receiver? When a user receives a notification I want them to open immediately to Fragment B of Activity A, for example. Is this possible? I feel like I should be able to force a fragment change from Activity A in its onCreate method using an intent extra...

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap getLargeIcon(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

        String uriString = null;
        try {
            JSONObject pushData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("com.parse.Data"));
            uriString = pushData.optString("uri");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v(getClass().toString(), "Unexpected JSONException when receiving push data: ", e);
        }
        Class<? extends Activity> cls = getActivity(context, intent);
        Intent activityIntent;
        if (uriString != null && !uriString.isEmpty()) {
            activityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString));
        } else {
            activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            activityIntent.putExtra("fragment", "fragment2");
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
        activityIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(cls);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(activityIntent);
            stackBuilder.startActivities();
        } else {
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivity (Activity A)**

In my onCreate I put the following:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.getString("fragment") != null) {
                /*Log.w(getClass().toString(), bundle.getString("fragment"));*/
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't automatically move to Fragment B.

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223298/how-can-i-launch-fragment-in-broadcast-receiver

Comment: That didn't seem to help.

Comment: Ok..I suggest you to mention this kind of similar questions SO link in your question otherwise someone will flag your question as duplicate.

Comment: @PravinDivraniya I provided an answer in that question you linked me and it works.

Comment: Does your logging show that the bundle correctly contains the string? After you've called `setCurrentItem` is there other code that will override the starting position?